# Create OpenGL object that always stays in GPU memory

Tags: opengl, gpu

Is there a method to create an OpenGL object that always stays in GPU memory (texture or buffer)? OpenGL can unload objects to RAM memory. But my purpose is to fill GPU memory. For example: I have 1 GB GPU memory and my app needs to fill 512 MB of GPU memory.

Comment: just create a VBO of that size..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a method to create OpenGL object, what stay in GPU memory always

No.

> But my purpose is fill GPU memory.

In other words you try to Denial-of-Service the GPU. Doesn't work. The OS/driver will decide to make space for other stuff, that needs to be drawn there and now. Many OSs these days rely on the GPUs 3D acceleration to draw their userinterfaces. The GPU always must be responsive.

Also modern GPUs have MMUs and can fetch only subsets of data in a larger object.

Comment: Thanks, I try to emulate few available video memory for my application.